# apt/maven/npm checksum failure on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apt, checksum, maven, npm

I'm recently encountering multiple download checksum failures when booting ec2 machine.
This manifests itself with sporadic failures of apt, maven and npm installs.
In one case that the pom checksum failed, I found a Fastly Debug message in the file.

Notes:

1. I'm using the standard ubuntu 12.04 ec2 image with a user-data script and running sudo apt-get update and dist-upgrade before anything else.
2. I acknowledge that preparing an image with packer.io would have reduced the number of sporadic failures, but that's out-of-scope for this question.
3. Could it be related moving from c1.medium to c3.large machines?

Comment: Are you using a proxy server?

Comment: nope. Standard ubuntu AMI. It's a sporadic error in the past few days.

Comment: Happened again: Bad MD5 hash for package